# Unable to kill the port 6379 used by redis installed with snap

Tags: linux, docker, redis

im confuse with redis instalation. I've already tried uninstall redis with any tutorials, also trying uninstall manually. But, redis still used 6379 port.

```bash
dna@dna:~$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6379
[sudo] password for dna:    
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      22141/redis-server  
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      22141/redis-server  
dna@dna:~$ apt-get autopurge redis-server
E: Could not open lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend - open (13: Permission denied)
E: Unable to acquire the dpkg frontend lock (/var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend), are you root?
dna@dna:~$ sudo apt-get autopurge redis-server
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
Package 'redis-server' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 45 not upgraded.
dna@dna:~$ sudo apt-get autopurge redis*
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package redis-stable
E: Unable to locate package redis-stable.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'redis-stable.tar.gz'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'redis-stable.tar.gz'
dna@dna:~$ redis-cli
```

my docker apps used redis already stopped, also the redis image already removed too.
Here's my os:

```bash
dna@dna:~$ hostnamectl
 Static hostname: dna
       Icon name: computer-laptop
         Chassis: laptop
      Machine ID: -------
         Boot ID: -------
Operating System: Linux Mint 21                   
          Kernel: Linux 5.15.0-41-generic
    Architecture: x86-64
 Hardware Vendor: Lenovo
  Hardware Model: -------
```

**[UPDATED1]**
thank you for answer me. Currently the problem still exist. By this update, here i give you my cmd input and output.

```bash
dna@dna:~$ docker ps
Cannot connect to the Docker daemon at unix:///var/run/docker.sock. Is the docker daemon running?
dna@dna:~$ sudo apt-get autopurge redis*
[sudo] password for dna:    
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package redis-stable
E: Unable to locate package redis-stable.tar.gz
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'redis-stable.tar.gz'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'redis-stable.tar.gz'
dna@dna:~$ redis-cli
Command 'redis-cli' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install redis-tools
dna@dna:~$ redis-cli ping
Command 'redis-cli' not found, but can be installed with:
sudo apt install redis-tools
dna@dna:~$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6379
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      961/redis-server *: 
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      961/redis-server *: 
dna@dna:~$ fuser -n tcp 6379
dna@dna:~$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6379
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      961/redis-server *: 
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      961/redis-server *: 
dna@dna:~$ kill -9 961
bash: kill: (961) - Operation not permitted
dna@dna:~$ sudo kill -9 961
dna@dna:~$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6379
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36248/redis-server  
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      36248/redis-server  
dna@dna:~$ ps -auxf | grep -i redis
dna        36284  0.0  0.0   9080  2396 pts/0    S+   13:02   0:00          \_ grep --color=auto -i redis
root       36248  0.2  0.1  53760  8212 ?        Ssl  13:01   0:00 /snap/redis/525/usr/bin/redis-server *:6379
dna@dna:~$ apt list installed | grep -i redis

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

dna@dna:~$ systemctl | grep -i redis
  run-snapd-ns-redis.mnt.mount                                                                                                                                       loaded active mounted   /run/snapd/ns/redis.mnt
  snap-redis-525.mount                                                                                                                                               loaded active mounted   Mount unit for redis, revision 525
  snap.redis.server.service                                                                                                                                          loaded active running   Service for snap application redis.server
dna@dna:~$
```

**[UPDATED2]**
trying to uninstall redis with snap

```bash
dna@dna:~$ sudo snap remove redis.server
[sudo] password for dna:    
snap "redis.server" is not installed
dna@dna:~$ sudo snap remove redis-525
snap "redis-525" is not installed
dna@dna:~$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6379
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36248/redis-server  
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      36248/redis-server  
dna@dna:~$ sudo snap remove redis.server ; sudo snap remove redis-525
snap "redis.server" is not installed
snap "redis-525" is not installed
dna@dna:~$ systemctl | grep -i redis
  run-snapd-ns-redis.mnt.mount                                                                                                                                       loaded active mounted   /run/snapd/ns/redis.mnt
  snap-redis-525.mount                                                                                                                                               loaded active mounted   Mount unit for redis, revision 525
  snap.redis.server.service                                                                                                                                          loaded active running   Service for snap application redis.server
dna@dna:~$ pkill -9 36248
dna@dna:~$ systemctl | grep -i redis
  run-snapd-ns-redis.mnt.mount                                                                                                                                       loaded active mounted   /run/snapd/ns/redis.mnt
  snap-redis-525.mount                                                                                                                                               loaded active mounted   Mount unit for redis, revision 525
  snap.redis.server.service                                                                                                                                          loaded active running   Service for snap application redis.server
dna@dna:~$ sudo netstat -tulnp | grep 6379
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6379            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      36248/redis-server  
tcp6       0      0 :::6379                 :::*                    LISTEN      36248/redis-server  
dna@dna:~$
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, there is your answer! redis is still installed, via `snap`.
This should do the trick:

```bash
sudo snap remove redis
```

---

What’s the output of `ps -auxf | grep -i redis`?

Perhaps another redis application is installed, what is the output of `apt list installed | grep -i redis`?

Also, what is the output of `systemctl | grep -i redis`

If all that doesn't bring any valueable hints, try to install mlocate w `apt install mlocate -y ; updatedb`.

Then perform a search for every redis file on disk:

`locate -i redis`

Comment: As you can see `apt` is being used, so it is not a RPM based OS, so `dnf` will not work.

Comment: question updated, please help

Comment: I've updated my answer, this should help you. You should be able to fix it yourself right now.

Comment: updated, still not working

Comment: Try to fiddle around w it, try `snap list | grep -i redis`, and copy that output to remove redis. You should have enough pointers to help you out in this use-case.

Try `sudo snap remove redis`

Comment: ok, worked. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find the PID that is listening on port 6379 with the following command: `fuser -n tcp 6379`

An example:

```
[root@server ~]# fuser -n tcp 22
22/tcp:               4837 34711
[root@server ~]#
```

If you cannot stop the service, you can kill it: `kill -9 <pid>`

Comment: question updated, please help

Comment: `pkill` would be a better option

Comment: @dhanyn10 It seems the service is starting right after you kill the PID, I think it is a container. What is the output of `sudo docker ps`

Answer (score -2):

You can try to login in as root, then uninstall redis-server. Because the account dna does not have access to read the file /var/lib/dpkg/lock-frontend.

Comment: by this line `dna@dna:~$ sudo apt-get autopurge redis-server` i've already login as root.